# df is reporting wrong information in an LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-space-utilization, ext4, df

I had a full disk usage on /var/log (100%) and deleted a few files to increase space. this is and ext4 partition mounted with default options.

However, when I df -h I get:

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-log             945M  885M     0 100% /var/log
```

Why is it reporting that 885M is 100% of 945M?

Answer (score 2):

The reserved space is not included in the % free. Run `dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/vg00-log` to see the reserved space ("reserved block count."). `tune2fs -m` will change that count.

See also, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/79981/df-h-shows-incorrect-free-space